# Creating a Simple SQL Query by concating condition based on Three Filters - Java & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have three HTML **Select** tags. The contents are as below:

1. All, Users, Guests
2. All, Approved, Rejected
3. All, Public, Private

I am doing following:

```
String by = //Some Code to get this value
String status = //Some Code to get this value
String privacy = //Some Code to get this value

String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM requests";

if(!by.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " WHERE SEARCH_BY='" + by + "'";;
}

if(!status.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " WHERE SEARCH_STATUS='" + status + "'";;
}

if(!privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " WHERE SEARCH_PRIVACY='" + privacy + "'";;
}
```

This will be a working query only if the user changes only one tag. But what if he changes two select tags: `searchQuery` will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE SEARCH_BY='Users' WHERE SEARCH_STATUS='Rejected'
```

I know i can use `AND` keyword like : `WHERE thisCondition AND thatCondition`

But What is the possibility of knowing that `thisCondition` exists(only if this select tag is not changed), it will make my query like this: `WHERE AND thatCondition`

In the End, I need something like:

```
Select * FROM requests WHERE SEARCH_BY='A' AND SEARCH_STATUS='B' AND SEARCH_PRIVACY='C';
```

Where `A`, `B` & `C` can be either All or a value. When it is All, I want it to contain all the results from database.

Something like: `WHERE SEARCH_BY='all'` should return all the rows of database rather than matching values of `SEARCH_BY` column to `all` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ensure that "by", "status" and "privacy" values are equals the select options. Written like that your code could be a victim of an SQL injection. There is many ways to do than. One and simple is:

```
public enum EBy {
    All, Users, Guests
}
public enum EStatus {
    All, Approved, Rejected
}
public enum EPrivacy {
    All, Public, Private
}
EBy eBy = EBy.valueOf(by);
EStatus eStatus = EStatus.valueOf(status);
EPrivacy ePrivacy = EPrivacy.valueOf(privacy);
```

Avoid using " WHERE 1=1" in an sql query. `SELECT * FROM t` is not equals `SELECT * FROM t WHERE 1=1` You could see that running "explain" on both queries.

```
String where = "";
if (eBy != null && eBy != EBy.All) {
    where += ((where == "") ? " WHERE " : " AND ") + " SEARCH_BY = '" + eBy.name() + "'";
}
if (eStatus != null && eStatus != EStatus.All) {
    where += ((where == "") ? " WHERE " : " AND ") + " SEARCH_STATUS = '" + eStatus.name() + "'";
}
if (ePrivacy != null && ePrivacy != EPrivacy.All) {
    where += ((where == "") ? " WHERE " : " AND ") + " SEARCH_PRIVACY = '" + ePrivacy.name() + "'";
}
searchQuery += where;
```

Are you using JDBC? Try to apply values on the prepared query instead of concatenating them in the query string. There are lot of materials over the internet for that, for example: [Preventing SQL Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Comment: What is the difference between ``eBy`` and ``eBy.name()``? and This query is used for a ResultSet. and I don't think a user can edit properties/values of select tag on my website. I insert that value from tag in query directly. There will be injection if they somehow managed to alter select variable only. right?

Comment: RE: What is the difference between ``eBy`` and ``eBy.name()`` because you use the ``enum`` object to match with ``Eby.All``, Then, why can't you output it in Query, why you needed to use ``eby.name()``?

Comment: 1. The user CAN edit the value that HTML sends to your server. Read more about SQL injections.

Comment: 2. "some string" + eBy + "some string" is equals to "some string" + eBy.toString() + "some string" That's why I preffer the eBy.name(), because I am not sure if there is no toString() method predefined for that enum. In a big application it is not a good idea to rely to toString() method, because someone could chage it, whithout even warning you :)

Comment: why a query with 'Where 1=1' is not equal to another query without it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM requests where 1=1";

if(!by.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " AND SEARCH_BY='" + by + "'";;
}

if(!status.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " AND SEARCH_STATUS='" + status + "'";;
}

if(!privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){
    searchQuery += " AND SEARCH_PRIVACY='" + privacy + "'";;
}
```

This uses a dummy condition so no matter how many other condition are meet, they will just be added as `AND <CONDITON>`.

Comment: Just want to confirm that it matches One Integer with another integer or I need to create a column named '1' and value '1'

Comment: Yes it matches an integer with another intenger, equals to true = true or 1>0 ETC.. no need to add anything. @rupinderjeet47